# Objective C , opening a website without opening it in Safari

Tags: objective-c, web-services

I am trying to find a way to load a website (for server call purposes) but I don t want it to open neither in safari nor in a UIWebView . I usually use this code for opening in safari

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

and for the UIWebViews

```
[web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thelink]]];
```

I tried to use the UIWebView without actually having a physical one but the page didn't load (I know that because the server call were not made at all)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
NSString *connected = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
```

if connected is != NULL then everything worked fine

Comment: Good for simple GETs, but for a POST, this method is entirely unusable.

Comment: How can this be the "correct solution"... inpatient user... sorry

Answer (score 3):

You should use NSURLRequest, for example:

```
NSString * url = @"http://myapi.mysite.com/api.php";
NSMutableURLRequest * aRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSHTTPURLResponse * httpResponse = nil;
NSError * urlError = nil;
NSData * responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:aRequest returningResponse:&httpResponse error:&urlError];
```

Where responseData is the body of the response, you can use httpResponse to check status codes etc...

Comment: You should never assume that the `NSURLResponse` returned by `+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` is a `NSHTTPURLResponse` object. It is much safer to perform `-isKindOfClass:` before assuming the type of subclass an object is.

Comment: Of course, I've omitted some checks such as a urlError, httpResonse different to nil etc

Answer (score 2):

[NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is your friend:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
// configure req to have post data and such

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];

// do something with data
```